# Can you use a semicolon to connect fragments that are one item in a vertical list?

Tags: style, punctuation, business-writing

I'm trying to write a numbered vertical list. The items are not complete sentences.

Can you use a semicolon to connect two fragments that are one item?

1. Receive guests; entertain guests

Or, should it be written as the following?

1. Receive guests and entertain guests

I looked at [6.130: Vertical lists—capitalization, punctuation, and format](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec130.html) in The Chicago Manual of Style. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find anything about using semicolons to connect fragments that are one item.

Edit: Receiving and entertaining guests have to be one item. I guess you could just write "receive and entertain guests" but I wanted to make it clear that it wasn't one continuous act.

Edit 2: Took out an unnecessary part. Also, the problem has been solved. Someone has kindly told me that the "fragments" are not fragments but imperative sentences! It means that the item consists of two complete sentences. So, it could be written as one of the following.

1. Receive guests; entertain guests.
2. Receive guests, and entertain guests.
3. Receive guests and entertain guests.

Edit 3: In the comments, I've explained why I thought that receiving guests and entertaining guests were not one continuous thing.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "Receive and entertain guests", since it is a single item?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I've edited my question. I want to write "Receive guests; entertain guests" so that it's clear that it isn't one continuous act. Also, receiving and entertaining guests have to be one item.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make this any clearer. If it *is* a single item, then it doesn't make sense to turn it into two. Why not use *receive and **then** entertain guests*? (Your problem doesn't seem to be with semicolons or fragments, but with phrasing.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my question again. Also, I've realized that it's just reception of guests. I was thinking "entertain guests" was the business entertainment of clients. But it makes no sense if it's taken that way. You're probably thinking of a duty of an employee of some kind of lodging business. It's about an ordinary business.

Comment: @JasonBassford It's indeed "receive and entertain guests." That's the reception of guests. Am I right?

Comment: @JasonBassford I should've said this: Also, regarding the item, I've realized that it's just reception of guests (I'm translating something.) My mistake was that I thought "entertain guests" was the business entertainment of clients. So, since it's the reception of guests, it can be written as " receive and entertain guests."

Answer (score 3):

I would be fine with either a comma or a semi-colon, although I think I'd prefer the semi-colon. Lists, particularly with sentence fragments, are pretty flexible in terms of content and punctuation. Just be consistent.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know that; I'll keep it in mind.